# how to view page in telegram-webapps instead of default browser

Tags: javascript, android, telegram

i have ploblem with telegram apps when i use them with android
when i click on href it use default browser to open page instead of webapp. it work ok on pc, ioc...

i have tried to use their lib to solve my problem

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;

         
            var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            links.forEach(function (link) {
                link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    loadContent(link.getAttribute('href'));
                });
            });
        });


function loadContent(url) {
    var tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
    tg.openUrl(url);
};
```

it still works correctly with pc or ios but when i click on href on android system it just doesn't do anything

how to fix this?